# Off-topic? Asking whether a Kerberos programming tool exists

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Would the question below be acceptable on Programmers?
If not, how could it be salvaged?

---

I am a programmer, and want to test my client software for Kerberos compatibility.
I need a Kerberos server to perform the tests.

Even though I am not a system administrator, I tried to set up a Kerberos server, but it looks that it is a job for specialists and will take days. In the end I probably won't be able to trust it to be really properly installed.

The [TurnkeyLinux Domain Controller](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller) distribution is nearly a perfect solution, and conveniently comes as a VM, but unfortunately it does only domain controller, not the Kerberos part.

Is there a similar tool that can be used as a Kerberos server too?

Comment: [Setting up FreeIPA on RHEL/CentOS](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Identity_Management_Guide/index.html) takes about 10 minutes after OS installation.

Comment: I would be interested in what unit tests are worth testing in Kerberos.  Could be on topic for Security.stackexchange.com...  Please @ me if you submit this question on any site so I can +1 and favorite.

Comment: your reputation ([over 20](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)) allows to ask questions like this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't seem like a good fit for any site on the network since it's a "shopping list" or recommendation-style question that tends to generate a large number of answers based on personal opinions rather than facts.